# Disable Defender but keep Windows Firewall active in Win10

Tags: windows, windows-10, firewall, windows-defender

In the latest Windows update (1803) it seems that the Windows Firewall is now part of Windows Defender.

Windows Defender is questionable and MsMpEng.exe continuously eats resources - I disabled Defender using the Local Group Policy (https://www.windowscentral.com/how-permanently-disable-windows-defender-windows-10).

However, I think that now the Windows Firewall is also disabled.

Is there a way to keep the Windows Firewall active but get rid of the Defender (again)?

Comment: You should be running *some* anti-malware suite. Reinstalling it should disable Defender and leave the firewall intact.

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to adjust the appropriate Local Group Policy settings to achieve your goal within Windows 10 version 1803.

Navigate to the following location in the Local Group Policy Editor:

```
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Defender Antivirus
```

On the right side, double-click **Turn off Windows Defender Antivirus** and change it to **Enabled**

[image: Local Group Policy Editor]

After you reboot your system and open the **Windows Defender Security Center**, you should see the following that indicates the Windows Defender Antivirus element is disabled:

[image: Windows Defender Security Center - Home]

However, if you highlight the **Firewall & network protection** subsection on the left, it will confirm that the Windows Firewall is still active:

[image: Windows Defender Security Center - Firewall & network protection]]